# How to use Progress Bar in java swing,while the function working in heavy process

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, method-call

I have created a class for uploading a data from excel format to mysql database. The class contains the method to upload into the database. I am using button to call the method. That uploading process taking very long time to upload So, I want to add a progress bar for that process anyone can help me to complete this process,

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4637215/230513)?

Comment: @trashgod not like that. i have called the func  which containing the heavy process on button click. no class extension used

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `SwingWorker` thread to do the processing and update the progress bar from that.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: could you add any example program

Comment: the link in the comment you replied to with "not like that. [...]" contains a working example using `SwingWorker`...